# How to install pg_amcheck in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

In 2022-06-16 [Postgres released version 14.4](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/postgresql-144-released-2470/), which fixes possible corruption on indexes created with the `concurrently` option.

The release notes suggest using `pg_amcheck` to check if we have corrupt indexes.

However, when running `pg_amcheck --heapallindexed my_database_name`, I get

```
pg_amcheck: warning: skipping database "my_database_name": amcheck is not installed
pg_amcheck: error: no relations to check
```

How one is supposed to install pg_amcheck on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

I tried installing `sudo apt install postgresql-contrib`, because `pg_amcheck` was supposed to be included, but to no avail, the same error message persists.

I even ran `CREATE EXTENSION amcheck;` inside `psql`, but I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: Did you run `CREATE EXTENSION amcheck` while you were connected to "my_database_name"?  You have to run it in each database you want to use it in.

Comment: @jjanes Yes I did run that on that very specific database. If I run it again it returns an error.

Comment: I can't reproduce that.  What if you drop and recreate the extension?  Are you sure you are connecting to the same system each time?  Do you have any 3rd party extensions installed?

Comment: @jjanes Janes, you were absolutely right, my bad. I re-read your comment and only then realized `CREATE EXTENSION amcheck;` had to be run AFTER connecting to my database by using `\connect MYDATABASE`; you solved it! Want to post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: `pg_amcheck --install-missing [other options]` would install the extension for you.