# PostgreSQL data corruption tools?

Tags: windows, corruption, postgresql-14

Are there any techniques/tools/methodologies for investigating row level corruption within a PostgreSQL table?

Most proposed solutions on this forum boil down to:

> try doing a `VACUUM FULL` to rebuild the table, if that doesn't work drop the table and restore from backup.

Is there anyway to actually fix the data? Is there anyway of reading and manually editing the raw PostgreSQL data files and removing / repairing just the corrupted rows?

The system I'm working on reads data straight from an external feed into a PostgreSQL table, and then shows evidence of corruption before the nightly backup process has had a chance to save it. Re-running the external feed is not an option, so in practice if I get any corruption at all, the whole day's data is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two (well, one and a wrapper) tools that can be included with PostgreSQL that may be able to help you here - [amcheck](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/amcheck.html) and [pg_amcheck](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgamcheck.html).

### amcheck:

`amcheck` is a [contrib module](https://pgpedia.info/c/contrib-module.html) (hereafter, cm) - these are  additional features provided as part of the source distribution but not enabled by default. Note that many of these cm's are **widely** used and also that many suggest that they should come by default - however, PostgreSQL's "lean and mean" philosophy means that they aren't and it may take the new user time to figure out exactly how to make the most of them.

The [`pg_stat_statements`](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2019/02/08/the-most-useful-postgres-extension-pg-stat-statements/) extension, for example, is widely used and recommended by all of the heavy hitters in the PostgreSQL community. BTW, "contrib module" and "extension" are [basically synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68873680/470530). Note however that while all cm's are extensions, not all extensions are cm's - far from it. For example, while neither [TimescaleDB](https://www.timescale.com/) nor [CitusData](https://www.citusdata.com/) are cm's (i.e. they're not bundled with the source code), they **are** extensions! There's a whole [PostgreSQL extension ecosystem](https://pgxn.org/) out there should you be interested.

Pardon the diversion, back to the point at hand!

> The amcheck module provides functions that allow you to verify the
> logical consistency of the structure of relations.

In PostgreSQL, a relation is either a table **or** an index.

> amcheck can be effective at detecting various types of failure modes
> that data checksums will fail to catch.

You can visit the amcheck page to get way more detail as to its functionality.

### pg_amcheck:

The pg_amcheck utility can be found in the `$PGHOME/bin` directory. It will **only** be found there if the database is compiled using `make world` or equivalent. It may or may not be installed on your own distribution depending - I can confirm that it is included in EnterpriseDB's Windows (14) distribution - I can't speak to other distributions at the moment.

As mentioned above, it's a wrapper around the `amcheck` extension:

> pg_amcheck supports running amcheck's corruption checking functions
> against one or more databases, with options to select which schemas,
> tables and indexes to check, which kinds of checking to perform, and
> whether to perform the checks in parallel, and if so, the number of
> parallel connections to establish and use.

The amcheck extension **must** be installed in order to be [able to use](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/313443/34007) the wrapper (makes sense!).

Please note (from the page):

- In general, amcheck can only prove the presence of corruption; it cannot prove its absence.
- (paraphrasing) - amcheck only works against B-tree indexes.

This latter is, (IMHO), a gross lacuna.

### Use case:

So, let's take a look at a practical use case for these tools.

- On 2022-05-24, Michael Paquier [tweeted](https://twitter.com/michaelpq/status/1529046530832797698) about a problem with potential corruption using PostgreSQL 14
- On 2022-06-02 An [article](https://pganalyze.com/blog/5mins-postgres-14-reindex-create-index-concurrently-bug-amcheck-extension) on pganalyze.com shows how to use amcheck to confirm the bug and see if it has affected your systems

### Summary:

The point here is - I think - that no system [is | can be | ever will be] perfect and that tools such as these [are | can be | may be] necessary from time to time in cases where there could be potential issues - it's a bit like the right to self-defence - you never want to have to use it, but you know that it's there in case you do!

N.B. PostgreSQL have since made an out-of-cycle release on 2022-06-09 - the great thing about all of this is that it was all done in the open, on mailing lists, for everyone to see!